# C# and a proper way of inheritence

Tags: c#, inheritance, logic

I'm working on a little space game.
There Ill need many buildings which can be build.
I dont think my idea of inheritance is correct ore useful and Im looking for a good way of checking the resources before constructing a building. If I intend 15+ resources, I dont wanna check each building for all resources.
Here is my idea of a building so far.
I would be grateful for any help!

````
namespace Space_Colony.Buildings
{
    class Building
    {
        String name = "undefined";
        int energyNeeded = 100000;
        int energyProduced = -100000;
        int buildTime = 100000;
    }

    class Solar_Panel_Weak : Building
    {
        String name = "Weak Solar Panel";
        int energyNeeded = 0;
        int energyProduced = 3;
        int buildTime = 20;

        int res_Needed_Wood = 10;
        int res_Needed_Iron = 10;
        int res_Needed_Sand = 10;
        int res_Needed_Electronics = 10;
    }

    class Landing_Field : Building
    {
        String name = "Landing Field";
        int energyNeeded = 0;
        int energyProduced = 0;
        int buildTime = 20;

        int res_Needed_Wood = 10;
        int res_Needed_Concrete = 10;
        int res_Needed_Color = 10;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

With your current code the subclass's attributes are completely different than the base classes attribute. You should change the access modifier of the attributes such that they are available to the subclass. You probably also want the Building class to be abstract so you can't instantiate it.

```
abstract class Building
{
    protected String name = "undefined";
    protected int energyNeeded = 100000;
    protected int energyProduced = -100000;
    protected int buildTime = 100000;
}

class Solar_Panel_Weak : Building
{
    int res_Needed_Wood = 10;
    int res_Needed_Iron = 10;
    int res_Needed_Sand = 10;
    int res_Needed_Electronics = 10;

    public Solar_Panel_Weak()
    {
        name = "Weak Solar Panel";
        energyNeeded = 0;
        energyProduced = 3;
        buildTime = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@danielm has illustrated inheritance well for your models, but I fear your subclasses might grow out of hand.

Say you have a `Settlement` class which is responsible for building the buildings you've defined. The required resources for each building is not mapped in a meaningful way to make a generic solution, for instance.

```
public class Settlement
{
    ...
    public void Build(Building building, Inventory inventory)
    {
        if (building is Solar_Panel_Weak spw)
        {
            // I've omitted validation for brevity
            inventory.UseResource("Wood", spw.res_Needed_Wood);
            inventory.UseResource("Iron", spw.res_Needed_Iron);
            inventory.UseResource("Sand", spw.res_Needed_Sand);
            inventory.UseResource("Electronics", spw.res_Needed_Electronics);
        }
        else if (building is Landing_Field lf)
        {
            // I've omitted validation for brevity
            inventory.UseResource("Wood", spw.res_Needed_Wood);
            inventory.UseResource("Concrete", spw.res_Needed_Concrete);
            inventory.UseResource("Color", spw.res_Needed_Color);
        }
        // So on...
    }
}
```

There will be a lot of repeated code, and will need to modify multiple places in the code to add a new building.

A similar issue is going to occur if you decide to let the subclasses handle building, as the way of handling needed resources will require each subclass to implement a `Build` method.

By restructuring your class to accept a list of materials, like:

```
public class Material
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int QtyRequired { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Building
{
    public IEnumerable<Material> MaterialsRequired = new List<Material>();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BuildTime { get; set; }
    public int EnergyNeeded { get; set; }
    public int EnergyProduced { get; set; }

    public Building(string name, int buildTime, int energyNeeded, int energyProduced)
    {
        Name = name;
        BuildTime = buildTime;
        EnergyNeeded = energyNeeded;
        EnergyProduced = energyProduced;
    }
}

public class SolarPanels : Building
{
    public SolarPanels() : base("Solar Panel", 20, 0, 3)
    {
        MaterialsRequired = new List<Material>
        {
            new Material { Name = "Wood", QtyRequired = 10 },
            new Material { Name = "Iron", QtyRequired = 10 },
            new Material { Name = "Sand", QtyRequired = 10 },
            new Material { Name = "Electronics", QtyRequired = 10 },
        };
    }
}
```

We can utilize a more generic approach to the problem of building like:

```
public class Settlement
{
    ...
    public void Build(Building building, Inventory inventory)
    {
        foreach (var material in building.MaterialsRequired)
        {
            if (inventory.HasRequiredMaterials(material))
            {
                inventory.UseResource(material);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, the class responsible for constructing buildings doesn't have to think too hard about making a building. I hope this helps a bit.